# Ansible delete stack with termination protection

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation

I am able to create a cloudformation stack with termination protection in ansible by adding `termination_protection: yes` to the creation part, but when it comes time to delete the task, I am having some trouble.

I've tried two approaches:

```
- name: "Disable termination protection and delete stack"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: [STACK NAME]
    termination_protection: no
    state: absent
```

This tells me that I need to disable termination protection before deleting the stack, which makes sense, however, when I try to do this:

```
- name: "Disable termination protection"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: [STACK NAME]
    termination_protection: no
- name: "Delete stack"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: [STACK NAME]
    state: absent
```

I am told that I need to pass the parameters to the cloudformation stack.  However, these parameters are defined upon stack creation, and I really shouldn't need to do this to disable termination protection.  Is this a bug in ansible or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to pass at least the template when you are trying to turn off `termination_protection`?

Comment: I shouldn't need to pass anything, I am able to use the CLI to turn off termination protection using only the stack name.

Comment: I don't disagree with you.  This is likely a limitation in the Ansible module as it is written currently.  I haven't looked through the code for the module, so I was curious if it was easy enough to work around for the time being.

Comment: Yes, for now I am just using the shell command to run AWS CLI commands.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the repository, in order to have the `termination_protection` updated, you need to have the `state: present` in the task.

See the call to the function [`update_termination_protection`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5eb311782264742451c5ae927bc6514f7e8e5793/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/cloudformation.py#L766) being enclosed in the condition [`if state == 'present'`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5eb311782264742451c5ae927bc6514f7e8e5793/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/cloudformation.py#L759)

So this should be your fix:

```
- name: "Disable termination protection"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: [STACK NAME]
    state: present
    termination_protection: no
- name: "Delete stack"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: [STACK NAME]
    state: absent
```

Which, in the end, makes sense, since you would not be able to update anything on an absent stack.

Comment: This doesn't work, state has a default value of present.